# Error MSB6006: "mainDexClasses" exited with code 2

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-multidex

I am beginning to develop a project in Xamarin Native but when I run the project the visual studio shows an error.. I am a noob in this technology so I can´t figure out what's the problem. I search a lot but can´t get the solution :)

the error is this :

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3):
>   Error MSB6006: "mainDexClasses" exited with code 2. (MSB6006)

if know the solution pls feel free to answer.

I am using JDK 8

Answer (score 0):

Ok I revolved this error just do this:

1 - uninstall de visual studio, install again

2 - Go to build-tools and remove the 26 preview folder

3 - go to platforms and remove android-26 folder